# Prototype of main() function in c or c++?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I was going through a tutorial and i have read there, that we can not define `void main()` as the prototype is already defined as `int main() or int main(int argc , char *argv)` these are only two valid way to define main function in C.
 so in which header file or library files these prototype are set 
I don't how compiler giving me error in case of `float main()` what is the mechanism behind, I mean is it a syntax error or some prototype defined for main()?

please suggest an answer in easy language.

Comment: There is no prototypes for it anywhere. This restriction is a part of the compiler itself.

Comment: "these are only two valid way to define main function in C" --> _almost_.  These (and equivalents) are only two _defined_ valid ways.  Other ones may exist per the implementation at the risk of losing portability,

Comment: Casting delete vote since every single answer posted contains factual errors. So this post causes more harm than good. To see what the standards actually say when they aren't incorrectly quoted, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518).

Comment: @Lundin An answer that quotes the standards precisely is not always the best possible answer.  It may, for instance, be too long and too full of standardese to be useful to beginners.

Comment: @zwol There's a lot of myths and weird dogmas about the format of main() floating around, SO gets confused "void main is not standard!" comments all the time. Even Bjarne Stroustrup managed to misunderstand the C standard in his C++ FAQ. That's why references to the actual standard are good, as a counter to factual errors or misinterpretations of the standard. As for keeping it simple for beginners, the linked canonical duplicate contains all kinds of answers: everything between brief summaries and in-depth language-lawyer answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your tutorial is not exactly *wrong*, but it describes the behavior of a very strict implementation, stricter than the C standard requires implementations to be.

What the C standard says about the function that is called on program start is just that certain possibilities are required to work.  It doesn't say that other things are required *not* to work.  Also, the C standard says very little about compiler errors.  It is common for modern C implementations to go well beyond the standard's requirements for diagnostics; it is also common for them to support many extensions to the set of programs they will accept.

In a  "hosted" environment, one that provides all of the facilities of the standard C library, programs that give the function called on program start the name and signature `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` are *conforming*.  They are required to work.  But the standard permits this function to be declared "in some other implementation-defined manner" as well, and many alternative names and signatures exist: I'm just going to list a few of the most common ones.

- `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)`
- `void main(void)`
- `int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)`

If your implementation documents that it supports one of these alternative entry point names or signatures, it's perfectly OK to use it.  (Your program will not be "strictly conforming", but almost no real programs are "strictly conforming", so don't worry about it.)

In a "freestanding" environment, which *doesn't* provide all of the standard C library, the name and signature of the function called on program start are left up to the implementation—you might have to use something wacky like `EFI_STATUS efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable)`.
However, it is common for `int main(void)` to work, and somewhat less common for `int main(int argc, char **argv)` to work (the arguments received at runtime may be garbage).

---

Now, what happens if you have a hosted environment and you use an entry-point function name and/or signature that isn't documented to work?  The C standard says that your program has *undefined behavior* in this case—*anything at all* is allowed to happen.  Some common things that will actually happen are:

- The compiler does issue an error, or at least a warning.  It's not getting the correct prototype from any header file when it does this; rather, the correct prototype is said to be *built in* to the compiler, defined in the compiler's own source code.  Nowadays this is the case for many C library functions as well as `main`.  A demonstration:

  ```
  $ cat > test.c <<\!
  extern int exit(int); // wrong, `exit` should return `void`
  void main(void) {}    // wrong, `main` should return `int`
  !
  $ gcc -fsyntax-only -std=gnu11 -Wall test.c
  test.c:1:12: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exit’
  test.c:2:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
  ```

  (For historical reasons, GCC is not nearly as picky about people's code as it could be; many of the things that, from a modern perspective, *should* be errors are merely warnings, and not even warnings that are on by default.  If you're writing new code from scratch and you use GCC, I recommend using `-std=gnu11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror` options basically always.  Not `-std=c11`, though, because that turns *off* extensions that you may need, and can also expose bugs in the system headers.)
- The program fails to link.  This is what happens, for instance, if you try to make up your own name, instead of calling it `main`:

  ```
  $ cat > test.c <<\!
  extern int puts(const char *);
  void my_program_starts_here(void) { puts("hello world"); }
  !
  $ gcc -std=gnu11 -Wall test.c
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:
      In function `_start':
      (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
  ```

  This is one of the more cryptic errors you can get out of the linker, so I'll unpack it a little.  Have you ever wondered how `main` gets called?  It's surprisingly simple: there's a function provided by the C library, conventionally called `_start`, whose last line is something like

  ```
  exit(main(argc, argv, environ));
  ```

  For historical reasons, this function isn't bundled with the bulk of the C library in `libc.so`.  It's in a separate object file, `crt1.o`, that the compiler automatically pulls in when asked to link a program (just like it automatically tacks on an `-lc`).  Thus, when you don't define `main`, the reference to `main` from `_start` is unsatisfied and the link fails.

  (OK, how does `_start` get called?  That's where you get into deeper magic.  Ask another question.)
- Finally, the program may compile and link fine and even *appear* to work correctly — but look harder and you discover that it is misbehaving.  This is what happens if you use `void main(void)` on a Unix system. (To first order, all hosted environments other than Windows are Unix systems nowadays.)

  ```
  $ cat > test.c <<\!
  extern int puts(const char *);
  void main(void) { puts("hello world"); }
  !
  $ gcc -std=gnu11 test.c
  $ ./a.out
  hello world
  ```

  Without `-Wall`, not a peep from the compiler, and the program ran fine...or did it?

  ```
  $ ./a.out ; echo $?
  hello world
  12
  ```

  The value that's supposed to be returned from `main` becomes the program's [*exit status*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html), which appears in the shell variable `$?`.  If `main` had been properly declared to return `int`, and there had been a `return 0;` at the end, the `echo $?` would have printed 0.  Where did 12 come from?  Probably it was the return value of `puts`, which the compiler did not bother clearing out of the return-value register before returning from `main`.

  It's easy to not notice this bug, but it *is* a bug and the first person who tries to write a shell script that involves your program will be annoyed with you.

---

Some footnotes about the exit status, mainly for pedants:

1. In C++, and in C starting with the 1999 standard, you are technically allowed to omit any explicit `return 0;` at the end of `main` as long as you declare it correctly, but I think relying on this is poor style.
2. On many but not all implementations of Unix, the value that shows up in `$?` will be only the low seven or eight bits of the value returned from `main`.  This is a limitation in the system call used to retrieve the exit status of a child process, [`waitpid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html).
3. A *strictly conforming* ISO C program can only return three values from `main`: 0, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`; the latter two constants are declared in `stdlib.h`.  The *effect* of returning zero from `main` is guaranteed to be the same as the *effect* of returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`, but the *values* are not guaranteed to be equal.

   In practice, it is safe to return at least 0, 1, and 2, and the implementations where `EXIT_SUCCESS != 0` and/or `EXIT_FAILURE != 1` have long since gone to the great bit bucket in the sky, so don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks zwol for the answer it is very helpful and very knowledgeable too.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and incomplete. There is no undefined behavior for `void main (void)` if that's the form that the compiler uses. Implementation-defined behavior. This is a common form in freestanding environments and fully acceptable standard C, see 5.1.2.1. What's important to note is that _the form of main is picked by the compiler_ not by the programmer. We only get UB if the programmer deviates from the form of main() that the compiler is using.

Comment: As for gcc, the correct compiler option to use for freestanding environments is `-ffreestanding`, which effectively turns all of this main() format disinformation irrelevant.

Comment: @Lundin The clause "or some other _documented_ possibility", in the very first paragraph, is intended to cover your objection.  If you find it inadequate, please be more specific as to what you want it to say; I do not currently see how it could be improved.

Comment: What I mean is that this answer only covers half of the standard, namely the hosted systems - where implementation-defined forms of main() may or may not be allowed (the standard is ambiguous there). There are not 2 standard possibilities, but rather 4: freestanding environment in which case the form is always implementation-defined (5.1.2.1), hosted environment with `int main (void)` (5.1.2.2.1/1 §1), hosted env. with the argv-argc  version (5.1.2.2.1/1 §2) or hosted env. with implementation-defined form (5.1.2.2.1/1 §3).

Comment: @Lundin OK, I added a bunch more text about this.  I'm not sure this makes it a better answer to the question OP actually asked, but it's at least more of an authoritative reference.

Answer (score 1):

The [C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) dictates what is valid and invalid C (older Standards had the same rules).

In respect to `main` signature it says ([5.1.2.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1)):

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

```
     int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
     int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent or in some other implementation-defined manner.

So, except for *some other implementation-defined manner*, the only valid signatures are those two.
If an implementation defines a different signature, you are free to use that signature provided you don't mind losing some code portability.

So the following are all invalid for a compiler without extras:

```
int main() { /* ... */ }
void main() { /* ... */ }
void main(void) { /* ... */ }
double main() { /* ... */ }
int main(int argc, double *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Suggest adding add if `int main()`, `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, etc. are valid.

Comment: Nothing in the question spoke of hosted environments. You are misquoting the standard by quoting the sub-chapter for hosted environments, thereby ignoring the whole chapter of freestanding environments in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a prototype for main function. It's the entry point of your program and it's defined by the standard.

for example c standard define it this way:

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void){}
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names >may be used, as they are local to the function in which they
>   are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}
> ```
>
> or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Comment: Nothing in the question spoke of hosted environments. You are misquoting the standard by quoting the sub-chapter for hosted environments, thereby ignoring the whole chapter of freestanding environments in the standard.

Answer (score -1):

Stick to the standard forms,

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

or

```
int main(void)
```

and you won't run into problems if you move a program from one compiler to another.
That said, **ISO/IEC 9899:201x -> 5.1.2.2.1**(Program startup) startup states :

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares **no prototype** for this function. It shall
>   be defined with **a return type of int** and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined
>   manner. .
>  .
>  .
>  <sub>10) Thus, int can be replaced by a
>   typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as
>   char ** argv, and so on.</sub>

Comment: Nothing in the question spoke of hosted environments. You are misquoting the standard by quoting the sub-chapter for hosted environments, thereby ignoring the whole chapter of freestanding environments in the standard.