# Output of "LCD_ALLCLR;" in C compiler what would be display on trainer kit?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, lcd

If we write down the line LCD_ALLCLR at the end of the code, what will be the output?
*Sample Code:

```
#define _LCD
#include &quot;mde8086.h&quot;

void main(void )
{
    int i;
    LCD_init;

    do {
           LCD_ALLCLR;
           LCD_puts( &quot;Serial monitor !&quot; );
           LCD_LN21;
           LCD_puts( &quot;MDA-Win8086 Kit!&quot; );

           for( i = 0; i &lt; 16; i ++ ) {
               wait( 15000 );
               LCD_RShift;
           }
       } while(1);
}
```

Comment: Other than formatting, may I suggest that you use the minimum _[conforming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543876/prototype-of-main-function-in-c-or-c)_ signature for `main`:  `int main(void){...`, then in the bottom of that function, include a return statement: `return 0;`.  And I am not sure what `#include &quot;mde8086.h&quot;` is.  (_besides wrong_)

Comment: I see you are kind of new to this site.  It is preferred (for your benefit) that questions be presented using a [mcve].